# Comment box for a music website with Php/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently designing a multimedia website were people can view a musician's biography.
I want the users to be able to comment on each biography page of a specific Musician.

I want people to be able to comment on each page separately without comments from one page showing up on another page. I would also like to include a thumbs up and down system for each comment.
Thank You in Advance::

Comment: Ummm....  Use WordPress or some other platform with a commenting infrastructure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is Google PHP comment box tutorial and you will find several tutorials on how to do this.  The answer is too long to put in this answer, so I will include a link to a tutorial that I found.  You may have to modify this a bit to include your specific field, but everything you need to know is in this tutorial.

www.findsource.com tutorial:
http://www.findsourcecode.com/php/commentbox.htm

In order to have this comment section on every page you would need to add the following code to each form:

`<input type="hidden" name="Mid" value="musician-id#">`

Then when you display the comments, you jut have to modify the query to something like:

`SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE Mid = musician-id#`

This will now work on each biography page.

Comment: Ok...your link looks cool, what I am actually saying is that:comment boxes should be show on diffrent pages(over 60 Musicians)

Comment: I apologize for not responding sooner.  I have added the multiple page answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `comments` table in the database. Insert a `MusicianID` field in it that points to a `musicians` table. When showing the musician page load every comments that has the correct `MusicianID`:

```
SELECT [...] FROM `comments` WHERE MusicianID = [id]
```

Comment: Thanks bro!.it contributed,Check out my new question